# Cursor doesn't seem to be working in android app

Tags: java, android, cursor

My cursor do not seem to be working. Can somebody please help me?
Actually the for loop here is not working. The log is not being shown.
This is my code:

```
public String getAFact(int rowNumber)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select mfacts from mfacts where osl_number=" + rowNumber + ";", null);
        for(c.moveToFirst();!c.isAfterLast();c.moveToNext()) {
            rowData = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME));
            Log.i("log_tag", "cursor isn't f**ked up..."+rowData);
        }
        c.close();
        db.close();
        return rowData;
    }
}
```

But anyway the following code is working fine and is showing the number of records correctly!

```
public int countRowsInDb()
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select * from mfacts",null);
        Log.i("Number of Records"," :: "+c.getCount());
        db.close();
        int c_getCount = c.getCount(); 
        c.close();
        return c_getCount;
    }
```

Comment: Does the table have a row where `"osl_number"` equals `rowNumber`?

Comment: Yes it has. But is there anyway where I can check it? Just to make it sure?

Comment: In Eclipse, you can use the File Explorer window to "pull" your database to your hard drive then check it manually. But if aren't seeing errors mentioning "index -1..." then the row probably doesn't exist.

Comment: If you are running your program in emulator, you can pull out the database file using File Explorer. /data/data/package name/ folder contains databases and other files used by your app

Comment: I have pulled the db but don't know how to check whether the table and rows are in there. Also please see the new edit. The counter is showing up correctly though!

Comment: Your edit makes it sounds like @Sam right with the idea that there is no row with osl_number == rowNumber.  If you run the same query as your edit in your original code, does it go through the loop?  If so, it is something to do with your `where` clause

Comment: On your hard drive in your `<Android-SDK>/tools/` folder you'll find `sqlite3.exe`, you can use this to perform command line queries on your SQLite file.

Comment: Or you can simply add sqlite plugin to Mozilla Firefox and use it to open database.

Comment: passionate androiden & @sam your tips were excellent in troubleshooting this. I was using osl_number instead of msl_number. osl_number has other data which was meant for something else. Thanks guys really appreciate this!

Answer (score 1):

I think your SQL statement is off.  It looks like you are trying to get the whole row of data, try

`"select * from mfacts where osl_number=" + rowNumber + ";"`

as your query.

Comment: Tried it, but still no luck! :/

Answer (score 0):

U can try for this..

```
  if (cursor.moveToFirst())
            {                       
                for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getCount(); i++)
                {
                    //Your logic goes here//
                    cursor.moveToNext();
//                   
                }           
            }
            cursor.close();
            db.close();
```

Comment: But this is what I do in the for loop right? I don't see any difference!

Comment: I am using this logic in my project..Its work perfectly..Then u have to check some other..Whether there is data in database?..Is logcat showing any error??